# Class 'myClassName' already exists in package 'myPackageName'

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-domain-class

I suddenly started facing a strange issue while working on my Grails application using IntelliJ. I have different domain classes and some other classes under `src/groovy`. When I open a class file to make some changes, I get an error that this class already exists in package which I don't have. I tried to rename the class using refactor but after that I still get the same error.

Can anybody suggest what's wrong here or if I did something wrong?

Comment: Now, Even I create a new Domain Class, Service or Grails Job for the very first time, I get this error

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38722853/437212 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/26987237/437212

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Clear" you project and build again.

Comment: You mean `grails clean`?

Comment: I have cleaned my application by 'grails clean' but for the time being error dis-appears but when I try to edit or even open that file, this error occurs again