# "Class already exists" error in IntelliJ on Groovy class

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

in IntelliJ (2016.2 and previous) we have our Groovy classes marked red with the error "class  already exists".
I think we can exclude that the cause is the stub-generation, as this is deactivated.

Probably it's caused in our constellation: We have included our compiled groovy (and java) classes in a jar that is registered as dependency.

Dependency MyProduct.jar contains `com.mycompany.MyGroovyClass`

Our source contains `com.mycompany.MyGroovyClass`

The error disappears if the dependency is registered with Test-Scope, in all other scopes the error appears.

However, in our structure we kinda *have* to include the compiled classes in a compile scope, as we want to avoid that each developer needs to compile all classes (I know about the compile in background ability, but we have a constellation that prevents this from working).

We have no errors in `com.mycompany.MyJavaClass` which exists as well in source and in MyProduct.jar.

Any ideas on how we can solve this?

Answer (score 7):

We've been suffering the same issue, it seems to be that IntelliJ registers the Java class, but also the Groovy class, and because of that it is showing that message (BTW, we are using a Maven Project).

So we ended up by going to the target folder -> right click -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded. Then, this setting will be saved on the IML file, and it won't happen again.

Hope it works for your as well! 
Cheers

Comment: You might also need to drill down a few directories under target and find the 'main' and 'test' directories, and mark them as excluded as well. In my project they are being automatically marked as 'generated-sources' even though their parent directories are marked as excluded (Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2017.1).

Comment: I have to mark directory as excluded every time when I run mvn clean install, as clean install wipes & recreate target folder

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `gmavenplus-plugin:1.5`
After marking `target/generated-sources/generated-sources/main` as "Excluded", The error disappeared. I even did "invalidate cache and restart", It persists the setting. This is great. `Intellij 2017.1.5`

Comment: it sounds like the problem you're describing is the issue of stubs not being ignored ([#58](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/issues/58)).  This is fixed in 1.6.

Comment: I'm not using any Intellij Plugins. Just plugin definition in pom.xml
I suppose you were not referring to plugin version in pom.xml. That didn't help.

Comment: I was referring to GMavenPlus 1.6. I renamed the goals to match IntellliJ's expectations.

Answer (score 1):

We have two ways to fix this issue

1. **Exclude Stub Directory**

target folder -> generated-sources -> groovy-stubs -> Right click main folder -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded

2. **Remove generateStubs goal from gmaven plugin**

Remove `<goal>generateStubs</goal>` from gmavenplus plugin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you Mark the src folder as Sources Root and do the same for the test folder

Then delete the target folder (most likely it's marked in yellow) and don't worry it won't delete any code from your project

If the issue persist, proceed to go to File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart